# Escopo de variável no JavaScript - Valor do atributo do DOM não é passado por atribuição

Tags: javascript, escopo-de-variáveis

Eu estava experimentando com JavaScript puro e me deparei com a seguinte curiosidade:

Quando eu passo os valores de referência em relação ao topo da página para variáveis, o código não funciona, quebra.

Assim funciona:

```
window.onscroll = function(){
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        backToTop.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        backToTop.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

Assim não funciona:

```
var distanciaTopoBody = document.body.scrollTop;
var distanciaTopoHtml = document.documentElement.scrollTop;

window.onscroll = function(){
    if (distanciaTopoBody > 20 || distanciaTopoHtml > 20) {
        backToTop.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        backToTop.style.display = "none";
    }
};
```

Percebam que o código não muda muito, é uma alteração visivelmente pequena, mas o resultado é completamente diferente.

Eu só atribui `document.body.scrollTop` a uma variável (*distanciaTopoBody*) e `document.documentElement.scrollTop` à outra (*distanciaTopoHtml*);

[**JS Fiddle para quem quiser testar**](https://jsfiddle.net/eduardowezzy/qdaqqnt6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

[`window.onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/onscroll) executa uma função toda vez que o `scroll` for rolado.

Então para que funcione, as variáveis devem estar dentro da função!

```js
var backToTop = document.getElementById("back-to-top");
window.onscroll = function(){
  var distanciaTopoBody = document.body.scrollTop;
  var distanciaTopoHtml = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (distanciaTopoBody > 20 || distanciaTopoHtml > 20) {
    backToTop.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    backToTop.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
#back-to-top {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px 7px 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  opacity: .7;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-out;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Back to top button using pure JavaScript -->
<a href="#" id="back-to-top">^</a>
<div style="height: 900px;"></div>
```

O mesmo vale para o evento [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/scroll).

```js
var backToTop = document.getElementById("back-to-top");
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  var distanciaTopoBody = document.body.scrollTop;
  var distanciaTopoHtml = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
  if (distanciaTopoBody > 20 || distanciaTopoHtml > 20) {
    backToTop.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    backToTop.style.display = "none";
  }
});
```

```css
#back-to-top {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px 7px 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  opacity: .7;
  transition: opacity .7s ease-out;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Back to top button using pure JavaScript -->
<a href="#" id="back-to-top">^</a>
<div style="height: 900px;"></div>
```

#### Referência

- [`window.onscroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/onscroll)
- [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/scroll)